# Not able to get through webseal authentication using rest-assured

Tags: rest-assured, webseal

working on an automation assignment and i am trying to test a web service hosted on a webseal server. the issue is i have pretty my tried every method in rest assured to get to the response json but what i am getting is the authentication screen html.

here is some of my non working code. what i was expecting it the json but no matter what authentication method i run i get the webseal's authentication page only.

```
private String serviceTestGET(WebServiceTest serviceTest) {
    System.out.println("Credential : " + userName + " -- " + password);
    // RestAssured.
    // RestAssured.authentication = basic(userName, password);
    // RestAssured.authentication = digest(userId, password);
    // RestAssured.authentication = oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret,
    // accessToken, secretToken);//form(userName, password);
    // RestAssured.authentication = form(userId, password, config);
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    return given().get(serviceTest.getEntryPoint()).asString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer after googling a bit.
there are few things we have to consider that webseal is going to authenticate the request by throwing back a authentication form. once that form is authenticated its expected that you will use the same session(cookies) to access the application behind the webseal server.

so here is my working code

```
    System.out.println("Credentials : " + username + " - " + password);
    RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    SessionFilter sessionFilter = new SessionFilter();

    Map<String,String> cookies = given().
            filter(sessionFilter).
            param("username", username).
            param("password", password).
            param("login-form-type", "pwd").
    expect().
        statusCode(200).
    when().
        post("https://your-web-seal-server/pkmslogin.form").getCookies();

    Reporter.log("Server Authenticated");

    return given().filter(sessionFilter).cookies(cookies).expect().statusCode(200).
    when().get(serviceTest.getEntryPoint()).asString();
```

Comment: Exactly, login-form-type is needed. Please see full documentation at  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSXJVR_2.0.0/com.ibm.sso.doc/wrp_config/task/tsk_submt_form_data_ws.html